# Does App WAIT for -initWithContentsOfURL: to retrieve web-data?

Tags: url, asynchronous, iphone

I am trying retrieve data from a .php file on a server from within an iPhone OS app. In one method, I employ the following code:

```
NSString *aString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:aURL encoding:anEncoding error:nil];

//See what I got
NSLog(aString);
```

When I run the App it seems like the App runs through the code so fast I doubt that there was enough time for a Data Request to have transpired. The resulting string is totally empty, which further supports my suspicions. What is happening here? Is the app not waiting for the -initWithContentsOfURL to retrieve data from the .php file on my server? If the app does not wait for this method, is there another method I can use to perform a Data Request in a manner that WAITS for the request to be completed before moving onto the next code?

(I've also read a little on NSURLConnection -- is this maybe what I should be looking into instead of -initWithContentsOfURL?)

Comment: The method call should wait while getting the data before it jumps to the next statement. Did you try and call the URL from a browser and see what data you get? Is the content-type in the header information of your response correct? Maybe you should try and get it in an NSData instead and get the string from the NSData?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSURLConnection is great for getting a file from the web... It doesn't "wait" per se but its delegate callbacks:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

...allow you to be notified when data has been received and when the data has been completely downloaded. This way you can have the App show (if you like) a UIProgressBar as the data comes in and then handle the file as you please when it is completely received.

Comment: these methods will only be called in case of a call using NSURLConnection and only when you are making asynchronous calls. The initWithContentsOfURL: will make a synchronous call